# Calling a function iteratively inside a view creation with PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, create-view

I have this table:

```
Account_id  |  ...    |   Message

111111      |  ...    |   blablablablabla
222222      |  ...    |   heyheyheyheyheyheyhey
111111      |  ...    |   blablablablablabla
222222      |  ...    |   heyheyheyhey
```

I've made a PL/SQL function that concatenates all messages for each account_id, however my function just do it for one account_id each time, because the input argument of the function is the account_id of the account of which I want the concatenate messages.

Now the problem is that I want to create a view of that table and run my function for all the account_id's, all at once.

How can I call my function iteratively during the view creation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help when you dont show any code, but I guess this could work:

```
Create Or Replace Force View Your_View As
--
Select Distinct your_function(yt.account_id)
--
From your_table yt
```